# Compare two tables without using column names mysql

Tags: mysql, join

I want to write a query where I need to compare two same tables and retrieve the unmatched columns with their respective table names from two different database which can be random. So, I cannot know the column names before the query execution.

Currently, what I can use it is

```
SELECT *
FROM schema1.Table1 t1 
LEFT OUTER JOIN schema2.Table1 t2 ON (t1.id = t2.id)
WHERE t2.id IS NULL;;
```

But, column names are not known before.

Example:
Table 1

```
col1  col2
1      a
2      b
3      c
4      d
```

Table 1(in different database)

```
col1  col2
1      a
5      b
3      c
4      e
```

How can I modify to do so?

Comment: Are you looking for the [INFORMATION_SCHEMA COLUMNS table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/columns-table.html)?

Comment: I advice you to read [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query) your question is not clear..

Comment: @Progman, Yes, but how to find the difference in both the tables?

Comment: @RaymondNijland, I have added an example

Comment: @P.Salmon, yes, something like that. Tables are same but are in different schemas, So, I want to check their data is different?

Comment: Not different , absent and no you would still have provide sql with the schema, table name and the column name(s) in the left join.Write once use many.

Comment: Do you absolutely have to do this in straight SQL? I ask, because I wasted ages trying to do something fairly similar in SQL, then wrote some PHP which delivered what I wanted really easily because I had access to PHP's fantastic array handling.